# Google Maps and .ejs files

Tags: javascript, google-maps, express

I am currently working on a node express application and have run into an issue when implementing the google maps javascript api. When I take the sample code from the google website and place it into a normal html page with my API key, the map runs fine. When I then try to place this code into a .ejs file and run it, nothing loads on screen. The controllers implemented on the same page work with no issues, the map just does not appear.
Below is the code I placed into the html file and tried placing into the .ejs file.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>   

    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>

      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }

      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
     <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD3AC6WEEZVQiqTVJsfbObHG-Pj6wwQaIc&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with ejs correctly. Are there any errors in console ?
Also you can compare generated html markup with expected...